# Automatically start Datawedge on MC65 running Windows Mobile 6.5.3

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, motorola, datawedge

I'm creating an autoinstaller for a customer that needs the Datawedge to be running.

We have done this in the past by configuring AppCenter to launch datawedge but this is not an option in this instance.

As part of the install process I have tried setting the following Regkey

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Motorola\DWStartUp]
"DontLoadOnStartUp"=dword:00000000
```

But Datawedge is instill  a "Stopped" state following a reboot.

At the moment I have created a shortcut to DataWedge.exe and placed it in `\Windows\StartUp` but this doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Windows CE's inherent launch capabilitiy?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Init]
"launch99"="DataWedge.exe"
"depend99"=hex:32,00 ; or whatever you need to launch before datawedge.  
                     ; Launch50 is often explorer
```